# Accessing current node in predicate with xsl:for-each

Tags: xslt-1.0, xpath-1.0

I'm stuck finding out how I can access the current node whilst iterating over a collection of nodes with `xsL:for-each`. This is my XML:

```
<events>
    <event>
        <date>
            <year>2012</year>
            <month>July</month>
        </date>
        <description>...</description>
    </event>
    <!-- more events -->
</events>
```

What I try to achieve is an HTML-representation like this:

```
<h2>2012</h2>
<dl>
    <dt>July</dt>
    <dd>One of these for every event with year=2012 and month=July</dd>

    <dt>August</dt>
    <!-- ... -->
</dl>
<h2>2013</h2>
<!-- ... -->
```

I'm using an XPath-expression to get all distinct years and then iterate over them calling a template called `year` with parameters `$year` and `$events`. Getting the value for `$year` is easy, but I'm struggling finding the right events. The following won't work, probably because `.` in the second predicate refers to the `event` being tested for the predicate. But how to access the `year` in there?

```
<xsl:template match="events">
<xsl:for-each select="event[not(date/year=preceding-sibling::event/date/year)]/date/year">
<xsl:call-template name="year">
    <xsl:with-param name="year" select="." />
    <xsl:with-param name="events" select="event[date/year=.]" />
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Many thanks in advance!

PS: Must work with XPath and XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kYear" match="year" use="."/>

 <xsl:key name="kEventByMonthYear" match="event"
  use="string(date)"/>

 <xsl:key name="kMonthByMonthYear" match="month"
  use="string(..)"/>

 <xsl:key name="kMonthByYear" match="month"
 use="../year"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:for-each select=
    "*/date/year
            [generate-id() = generate-id(key('kYear', .)[1])]
    ">
   <h2><xsl:value-of select="."/></h2>
   <dl>
      <xsl:apply-templates select=
      "key('kMonthByYear', current())
           [generate-id()
           =
            generate-id(key('kMonthByMonthYear',
                             string(..)
                         )[1]
                     )
            ]"/>
      </dl>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="month">
    <dt><xsl:value-of select="."/></dt>

    <xsl:for-each select=
    "key('kEventByMonthYear', string(current()/..))">
     <dd><xsl:value-of select="description"/></dd>
    </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document:**

```
<events>
    <event>
        <date>
            <year>2012</year>
            <month>January</month>
        </date>
        <description>Jan1</description>
    </event>
    <event>
        <date>
            <year>2012</year>
            <month>January</month>
        </date>
        <description>Jan2</description>
    </event>
    <event>
        <date>
            <year>2012</year>
            <month>March</month>
        </date>
        <description>Mar1</description>
    </event>
    <event>
        <date>
            <year>2012</year>
            <month>March</month>
        </date>
        <description>Mar2</description>
    </event>
    <event>
        <date>
            <year>2012</year>
            <month>March</month>
        </date>
        <description>Mar3</description>
    </event>
    <event>
        <date>
            <year>2012</year>
            <month>July</month>
        </date>
        <description>Jul1</description>
    </event>
    <event>
        <date>
            <year>2012</year>
            <month>July</month>
        </date>
        <description>Jul2</description>
    </event>
    <event>
        <date>
            <year>2012</year>
            <month>September</month>
        </date>
        <description>Sep1</description>
    </event>
    <event>
        <date>
            <year>2012</year>
            <month>October</month>
        </date>
        <description>Oct1</description>
    </event>
    <event>
        <date>
            <year>2012</year>
            <month>October</month>
        </date>
        <description>Oct2</description>
    </event>
    <event>
        <date>
            <year>2012</year>
            <month>November</month>
        </date>
        <description>Nov1</description>
    </event>
    <event>
        <date>
            <year>2012</year>
            <month>November</month>
        </date>
        <description>Nov2</description>
    </event>
    <event>
        <date>
            <year>2012</year>
            <month>December</month>
        </date>
        <description>Dec1</description>
    </event>
    <event>
        <date>
            <year>2012</year>
            <month>December</month>
        </date>
        <description>Dec2</description>
    </event>
    <event>
        <date>
            <year>2012</year>
            <month>December</month>
        </date>
        <description>Dec3</description>
    </event>
    <event>
        <date>
            <year>2013</year>
            <month>January</month>
        </date>
        <description>Jan1</description>
    </event>
    <event>
        <date>
            <year>2013</year>
            <month>January</month>
        </date>
        <description>Jan2</description>
    </event>
</events>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<h2>2012</h2>
<dl>
   <dt>January</dt>
   <dd>Jan1</dd>
   <dd>Jan2</dd>
   <dt>March</dt>
   <dd>Mar1</dd>
   <dd>Mar2</dd>
   <dd>Mar3</dd>
   <dt>July</dt>
   <dd>Jul1</dd>
   <dd>Jul2</dd>
   <dt>September</dt>
   <dd>Sep1</dd>
   <dt>October</dt>
   <dd>Oct1</dd>
   <dd>Oct2</dd>
   <dt>November</dt>
   <dd>Nov1</dd>
   <dd>Nov2</dd>
   <dt>December</dt>
   <dd>Dec1</dd>
   <dd>Dec2</dd>
   <dd>Dec3</dd>
</dl>
<h2>2013</h2>
<dl>
   <dt>January</dt>
   <dd>Jan1</dd>
   <dd>Jan2</dd>
</dl>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of the **[Muenchian method for grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)** -- with composite grouping keys.

Comment: Thank you! The use of keys is again something completely new to me. Right now I found another possibility and will post it as an answer below. Just for my curiosity: Is there any straight forward solution for the original "accessing current node of an iteration" problem?

Comment: @hielsnoppe: You are welcome. Please, define "straightforward" :). For me this solution is the most straightforward XSLT 1.0 solution that I am aware of -- otherwise I would have provided another one.

Comment: Let me put it this way: Your solution makes my transformation work, which is great, but doesn't answer the question whether or not - and in case yes, how - I can access the aforementioned property. Doesn't matter though, 'cause it works. :-)

Comment: @hielsnoppe: I am afraid I don't understand the "original question". You could probably work out a simpler and easier to explain example (try to avoid such words as "aforementioned") and then use it to ask a new question. As for the current problem, this is well-known as "grouping" and has a definite, easy and almost mechanical solution in XSLT 1.0. In XSLT 2.0 things are made even much easier. It might be that you are simply needing the `current()` function, but I can only guess without fully understanding this question.

Comment: Yes, I probably could have built a simpler example. Right now I am glad to have things working, but maybe sometime soon I will. `current()` did not work for me, because same as `.` in the predicate it refers to the element to be tested and not to the current element of the iteration. Next time I'll make sure to be more precise, let's leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

@Dimitre Novatchev's answer is the more elaborate one, but I found another possibility I'd like to share. It doesn't depend on `key`s and therefore is a bit more "newbie-friendly". On the other hand it too doesn't solve the original "accessing current node of an iteration" problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="events">
        <xsl:for-each select="event[not(date/year=preceding-sibling::event/date/year)]/date/year">
            <xsl:call-template name="year">
                <xsl:with-param name="year" select="." />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="year">
        <xsl:param name="year" />

        <h2><xsl:value-of select="$year" /></h2>

        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <xsl:for-each select="//event[date/year=$year][not(date/month=preceding-sibling::event[date/year=$year]/date/month)]/date/month">
            <xsl:call-template name="month">
                <xsl:with-param name="month" select="." />
                <xsl:with-param name="year" select="$year" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </dl>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="month">
        <xsl:param name="month" />
        <xsl:param name="year" />

        <dt><xsl:value-of select="$month" /></dt>

        <xsl:for-each select="//event[date/year=$year][date/month=$month]">
            <xsl:call-template name="event">
                <xsl:with-param name="event" select="." />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="event">
        <xsl:param name="event" />

        <dd><xsl:copy-of select="description/node()" /></dd>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: If "it sometimes screws up the markup for a yet unknown reason and too doesn't solve the original "accessing current node of an iteration" problem" then, with all due respect", this isn't actually a solution to the problem.